# Vista previa no disponible en modo móvil

Tags: bug, ediciones, web-móvil

Editando / respondiendo una pregunta desde el modo escritorio tenemos la vista previa al final de la página, esto es muy útil para verificar que la respuesta tendrá la visibilidad esperada.

Al estar en modo móvil no logró ver esta característica, probablemente sea un problema de compatibilidad con el dispositivo.

- Huawei p30
- Chrome 89.0.4389.105

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: hablas de la app stackexchange?

Comment: Sitio web desde el celular, esto de manera general

Comment: Varias cosas.. esto no seria un bug necesariamente. Luego, si esto fuera un problema, seria de toda la red y habria que publicarlo en https://meta.stackexchange.com/ que es donde se publican las cosas que afectan a la red. Luego esto pasa en todas las versiones moviles. Se podria pedir alli la mejora, pero ya eso depende de SO y no de alguno de nosotros en particular. Se entiende?

Comment: Así es ,  es algo general enbla red de stackexchange.

Comment: Al principio creí q la característica no existía , después vi que  usando el emulador desde Chrome  para iPhone , Samsung , etc...  Parece ser q si lo contempla. Probare descargar la app suena a una buena alternativa, gracias!

Comment: Lo moveré a el meta general